# Swift's replaceSubrange in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

What would be an elegant way of achieving something like Swift's:

```
sections.replaceSubrange(sectionIndex ..< (sectionIndex + 1), with: [section])
```

in Kotlin?

My code so far:

```
var filters = BehaviorRelay.create<List<FilterSection>>()

 fun updateFilters(type: FilterType, filtersArray: List<Filter>, state: SectionState = SectionState.Loaded){
        val sectionIndex = filters.value.indexOfFirst { it.filterType == type }
        val section =  filters.value[sectionIndex].update(state, filtersArray)
        val sections = filters.value
        //here is where I need to replace the elements
        filters.accept(sections)
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in function for that in the standard library. You can, however, define an extension as follows:

```
fun <T> List<T>.replaceSubrange(subrange: IntRange, withItems: List<T>): List<T> =
    take(subrange.first) + withItems + drop(subrange.endInclusive + 1)
```

> ```
> > listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).replaceSubrange(1..3, listOf(0, 0, 0, 0))
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5]
> ```

Or, if you only need to insert a sublist into a list:

```
fun <T> List<T>.insertSubrangeAt(index: IntRange, items: List<T>): List<T> =
    take(atIndex) + items + drop(atIndex)
```

> ```
> > listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).insertSubrangeAt(1, listOf(0, 0, 0, 0))
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> ```